How to highlight specific keywords throughout the browser from session storage using React without Chrome extensions?
I want to build a functionality in my React app where specific keywords, stored in session storage, are highlighted across all web pages visited in the browser. I don't want to rely on Chrome extensions or any external plugins. Instead, I want the React app to handle this. The keywords will persist using session storage, and the app should retrieve them to apply the highlights on any page.
Has anyone implemented something similar? How can I achieve this in a React app?

The keywords should be stored in session storage.

When a page is loaded, the React app should read the session storage and highlight the matching words on that page.

I don't want to use browser extensions or external libraries for this.


Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
